# Powershell script to Generate alert on Memory and CPU usage

Tags: sql-server, powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

"I want to write a powershell script which will generate alert on two parameters: CPU and Memory.
I will be using WMI objects and the script should generate an alert once threshold is reached for any one of them.(The threshold is say 80%)
A further enhancement would be if i could run this script on remote servers as well.
Is there a way to find which wmi-object class to be used and how the general script should look like.
I am using for 64 bit machine"

Comment: This is a task much better suited to a network monitoring system like Paessler; I'm sure there are about a dozen others available at various price points & feature lists.

Answer (score 1):

In PS2.0 you have cmdlets that gets live, real-time performance counter data directly from WMI.

Check:

```
Get-Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes'
Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time'
```

And of course:

```
Get-Help Get-Counter
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks.... One question though... Can we put conditions on the output of these two commands... like send an e-mail if avail mem is less than 300 MB?...

Comment: You're writing a script, so you can do whatever you want with the output of the cmdlets. Run the cmdlet, store its output in a variable, and then write logic around that variable to test its value and take the appropriate action. That said, monitoring like this is still better suited to a network monitoring suite.

Comment: Of course you can do that. Just save output of Get-Counter to a variable and make whatever condition you want. You have a bunch of SO questions regarding how to send an email from PS.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be WMI ?   Were I to be attempting to do this via powershell I would simply use [get-counter as demonstrated here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872428.aspx).  There is also a [good MVP example here](http://computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_get_counter.htm).

If you are really stuck on WMI then the MVP link offers some advice that direction as well but not nearly as much in the way of code sample.

Also keep in mind that you have to take into account [how many cores/processors](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/winserverpowershell/thread/8d7502d4-9e67-43f7-94da-01755b719cf8) you're monitoring as it effects what the value of get-counter really means.

Comment: Write function named WmiGetCounter which calls Get_Counter.  Manager will never know how it works. He learned about the WMI thing at some seminar somewhere, and he was happy to be able to insert some tech-speak in there, wasn't he?